# How can I put an user inputted number to a double unless a bigger number is inputted in Java

Tags: java

New to Java and stuck on something. I want to write a program where an user inputs a double and the number sticks to it unless a bigger number is inputted. I currently have this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class U4_L2_Activity_Three{
 public static void main(String[] args){

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   int x = 1;
   while (x != 0 && !(x > 1) && !(x < 0)) {

     System.out.println("Please enter the longitude:");
     double lon = scan.nextDouble();
     double MaxLon = 0;
     System.out.println("Please enter the latitude:");
     double lat = scan.nextDouble();
     double MaxLat = 0;
     System.out.println("Would you like to enter another location (1 for yes, 0 for no)?");
     if (lon > MaxLon && !(lon > 180 || lon < -180)) {
       MaxLon = lon;
     }
     MaxLon = MaxLon;
     System.out.println(MaxLon);
     x = scan.nextInt();
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored few condition and group the relative command following the order.

I don't see the lat condition, so i used the same with lon condition, you might change it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);) {
      int x = 1;
      double maxLon = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
      double maxLat = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
      while (x == 1) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the longitude:");
        double lon = scan.nextDouble();
        if (lon > maxLon && inRange(lon, -180, 180)) {
          maxLon = lon;
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the latitude:");
        double lat = scan.nextDouble();
        if (lat > maxLat && inRange(lat, -180, 180)) {
          maxLat = lat;
        }

        System.out.println("maxLon:" + maxLon);
        System.out.println("maxLat:" + maxLat);
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another location (1 for yes, 0 for no)?");
        x = scan.nextInt();
      }
      System.out.println("Exit.");
    }
  }

  private static boolean inRange(double val, double begin, double end) {
    return val >= begin && val <= end;
  }
```